# Get file extension in Ruby without params

Tags: ruby

in Ruby, how do you get the file's extension name without params?

When I do this:

```
File.extname('https://www.example.com/image.jpg?v=1616005208')
```

I get back:

```
.jpg?v=1616005208
```

This isn't ideal, when I only want the extension. How do I return only `.jpg`?

Comment: That's not a path, that's a URI. You need to parse it as a URI, not a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the path first with [`URI#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) and [`URI::Generic#path`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3198e7abd70bd2af977f2bb6c967e9df8f91adb0/lib/uri/generic.rb#L260) and then use that as the argument for extname:

```
require "uri"

File.extname(URI.parse("https://www.example.com/image.jpg?v=1616005208").path)
# ".jpg"
```

With the release of Ruby 3 the uri library isn't a built-in anymore, so you'll have to require it depending on your Ruby version.

Comment: Should really be `require 'uri'` as `'open-uri'` is a whole different thing that just happens to include URI.

Comment: That's right @tadman, thanks for explaining that.